# Functional programming design: A case about Memo in scalaz

Tags: functional-programming, scalaz

I've been using `Memo` from scalaz for a while, however, here is the situation that I feel I am not able to remain `pure`.:

```
def compute(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {a+b} //an expensive computation
val cache = Memo.immutableHashMapMemo[(Int, Int), Int]{
  case ((a,b)) => compute(a,b)
}
```

Now, I have `s1` and `s2` both in type `Set[(Int, Int)]`. For example, `s1 = Set((1,1), (1,2))` and `s2 = Set((1,2), (1,3))`. Each list has to be run in parallel:

```
def computePar(s: Set[(Int, Int)]): Set[Int] = //using compute() in parallel
```

So the issue is each time I can only get the list of the results from an input list. While my `Memo` should still be `Map[(Int, Int), Int]` because you can reuse `compute(1,2)` from `s1` for the first element in `s2`. Using a mutable map should solve the problem. I just wonder if there is a FP solution. I feel it might be related to `Kleisli` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be similar to this one: [Pimping scalaz Memo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238362/pimping-scalaz-memo)

You will find solution to your problem there i think, but i have something more to say about TrieMap(structure proposed in linked question). It scales well with number of threads (horizontal scaling is very good), but it has quite a big constant cost of operations.